# IOS: uilabel cut my word

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a problem with label and I don't understand where is the solution.
I set my label with "Word Wrap" and 3 lines but it cut a word when text wrap...why??
thanks

Comment: Show some code and better describe (screen shot?) the result.

Comment: Is it a single word in your label?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**edit**: Somehow this still gets views. More recent versions of iOS no longer have as many issues with UILabel, so this no longer applies. (especially with Auto Layout)

This is a really common problem when trying to use multi-line UILabels. The short answer is to use a UITextField instead if you want multiple lines of text. You get more control over the padding around the text as a bonus.

(yes, you can 'fix' the UILabel but sometimes simpler solutions are better)

Comment: Can you explain how using a `UITextField` is better or easier than using a `UILabel` to show some static, wrapped, multi-line text?

Comment: Never had it break on multi-line text, even when changing font. You also get to control the padding, can set a background in IB. I generally think of UILabels for single-line text, but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bounds are too small? Stretch the UILabel out as much as possible (height-wise), set lines to 999 and see if it still cuts it.